# Benutzung von "strange"

Tags: word-usage

Ich habe bemerkt dass meine Kollegen immer häufiger die englische "strange" verwenden. Z.B. "Das ist ja strange."

Dafür kann man doch auch "komisch" benutzen. Ist diese Anwendung aus irgendwelcher Film bekannt geworden und daher trendy? Oder macht es besonders gutes Gefühl im Mund zu sagen? Oder einfach so?

Comment: Seltsam, in meinem Umfeld hab ich davon noch nichts mitgekriegt.

Comment: Ich kenne das schon seit meiner Jugendzeit in den neunzigern. Ich glaube nicht, daß es *eine* spezifische Quelle hat - es ist einfach der Einfluß englischsprachiger Kultur.

Comment: Achso. Okay :) Danke.

Comment: Ständig Amerikanismen zu verwenden ist pathetisch.

Answer (score 3):

Eine Motivation für die Benutzung des englischen Worts ist, dass es durch die fremde Aussprache die eigene Bedeutung im deutschen Redefluss darstellt.

Als deutschsprachiges Äquivalent würde ich "seltsam" verwenden.

Answer (score 2):

Ich glaube, dass das Wort schon länger im Deutschen als Fremdwort in Verwendung ist. [Duden online führt das Wort jedenfalls auf](http://www.duden.de/rechtschreibung/strange) mit der Bedeutung

> sonderbar, merkwürdig, befremdlich

Und dem Beispiel

> ein bisschen strange fand sie sein Verhalten schon

Eine Analyse mit dem Google Ngram Viewer ist in diesem Fall leider nicht möglich, da es ein Substantiv gibt, das (altmodisch) dekliniert gleich geschrieben wird: *mit dem Strange*. (Strang = Seil)

Comment: Der Ngram Viewer [kann Groß- und Kleinschreibung unterscheiden](http://ngrams.googlelabs.com/graph?content=strange%2CStrange&year_start=1800&year_end=2008&corpus=8&smoothing=3), aber ich weiß nicht, wieso dann "strange" schon so lange existiert. OCR-Fehler?

Comment: @Hendrik_Vogt hm, echt STRANGE! ;)

Comment: Check [this one](http://www.dict.cc/?s=Strange)!

Answer (score 2):

Im Gegensatz zum Duden listet dict.cc das Wort im Deutschen als umgangssprachlich auf. Das DWDS enthält es überhaupt nicht. *Strange* wird vermutlich gerne verwendet, weil es ja *cool* ist, englische Begriffe im Deutschen zu verwenden.

Je nach Umfeld klingst du daher möglicherweise sehr *strange*, wenn du das Wort verwendest, weshalb ich die Verwendung vermeiden würde - umgekehrt wird dich niemand *verschroben* nennen, weil du es nicht verwendest. Ich finde es jedenfalls ziemlich albern (Achtung: Dies war eine kostenlose subjektive Meinung), zumal es so viele Alternativen gibt (Liste aus dict.cc). Andererseits haben natürlich durchaus auch *gediegene* Wörter wie *cool*, häufig über die *seltsame* Sprache der Jugend, den Weg ins Deutsche gefunden und wirken keineswegs mehr *skurril*.

- skurril
- verquer
- seltsam
- verdreht
- unbekannt
- sonderbar
- ungewohnt
- unüblich
- befremdend
- mysteriös
- fremdartig
- auffallend
- eigenartig
- wunderlich
- befremdlich
- merkwürdig
- verschroben
- absonderlich
- nicht normal
- eigentümlich
- verwunderlich
- ulkig [ugs.]
- eigen [geh.]
- nicht geläufig
- außerordentlich
- außergewöhnlich
- verkorkst [ugs.]
- sonderlich [sonderbar]
- komisch [ugs.: seltsam, verdächtig]
- gediegen [ugs. für: wunderlich, seltsam] [norddt.]

Hinweis: Einige dieser Übersetzungen gehen auf die Bedeutung im Sinne von *fremd* ein, die das Wort im Englischen hat. Als solches wird es aber gewöhnlich im Deutschen nicht verwendet, aber wenn jemand *strange* ist, kann er durchaus auch *befremdend* oder *fremdartig* sein, daher habe ich diese Einträge in der Liste belassen.